# Identify values in column A not in column B and column C using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python newbies looking for help. A dataset has 3 numerical columns: A, B, C. How do I find the values only exist in A but not B and C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question need more details but you can adapt the code below:

```
A = [1, 2, 3]
B = [1, 3, 4]
C = [1, 4, 5]

>>> set(A).difference(set(B).union(C))
{2}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your dataset is CSV or .xlsx, then you can use pandas to process.

```py
import pandas as pd
 
df = pd.read_csv('path/to/file') # if file is csv

# if file is xlsx
# df = pd.read_xlsx('path/to/file')

a = df['A'].unique()
b = df['B'].unique()
c = df['C'].unique()

diff = set(a).difference(set(b).union(c))
```